# Как добавить Gradle к существующему проекту?

Tags: android-studio, android, gradle

Доброго времени суток! 
На данный момент пользуюсь Android Studio, хотелось бы узнать как добавить Gradle к существующему проекту. При создании нового проекта не возникает проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как обычно говорят - хорошо почитать хелп. Это все [описано](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html). Но там все для эклипса.

А вот андроид-студия должна вообще то сама ковертировать при старте. Но у меня не получилось. Возможно она не конвертирует проекты только с idea.

Comment: я все это читал и только потому уже пришел сюда :)
вот в том то и проблема, что проект IDEA

Comment: [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606727/import-project-from-intellij-idea-to-android-studio) пишут, что это вроде невозможно и предлагают костыль.

Comment: спасибо :) буду пытаться

Answer (score 0):

Если Android Studio сама не создает файлы Gradle, попробуйте следующее (мне помогало):

Tools=>Android=>Sync Project with Gradle Files